# A Boundedness and Precompactness question

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Let $l_{1+} = \{ x=(x_n)_{n=1}^{\infty} : p_{\alpha}(x):=(\sum_1^{\infty}
|x_n|^{\alpha})^{1/\alpha} < \infty, \forall \alpha >1 \}$, and let the
topology be given by the norms $(p_{\alpha})_{\alpha>1}$.

For $A_B = \{ (\frac{log^{\beta}n}{n})_{n=2}^{\infty}, \beta \in B\}$
find a criterion for the set B(parameter set) such that

i) $A_B$ is bounded

ii) $A_B$ is precompact

Is $l_{1+}$ a Montel space?

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I am not very good at the subject but here is what I think:

For $\alpha>1$ the sum $\sum_{n=2}^\infty (\frac{\log^{\beta}(n)}{n})^{\alpha}$ converges by comparison test and $\beta$ does not matter, i.e, $B=\mathbb{R}$ for boundedness.

For precompactness we need to show that there exist a finite $\epsilon$-net that covers $A_B$. Since sum starts at $n=2$ we don't get any problem for negative $\beta$, and I think we can find a maximum, say $M$. For fixed $\epsilon$, the tail of the sequence, after some $N$ inside of $\epsilon$ strip, and the ones can before that can be put in a finite $\epsilon$-net($N.M/\epsilon$ parts).

For Motel space I am not sure but if it is you need to show a set is precompact iff it is bounded for all sets.

Note: Nowadays, I am also studying this subjects so I tried to help out, but I am not sure it is true entirely.